# Stripe charging customer directly from their Credit balance

Tags: api, stripe-payments, payment, strip

I am having trouble charging user directly from their Credit balance. I have added some credit balance on stripe customer. Lets take a scenario that my client have 50$ in his credit balance. He/She create a new order of 60$. I want to charge him 10$ only from his card. And rest should be charged from his credit balance.

I was successfully able to retrieve the Credit balance for customer. But when ever I create a charge, It always charge it from credit card which is saved (default) or card given at time of checkout. I searched for this that how we can create a charge directly from credit balance but was not able to find anything.

I read somewhere that stripe directly create the charge from credit balance first and then it charge from default card/given card. Is this true?

Can someone please send me a help link on how I can charge customer from their credit?
What API to call when charging them via credit balance?
Is this something I had to do manually (Calculate credit balance and deduct it and then charge more from card if needed) or is there any mechanism available?

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 2):

Stripe Customer credit balances only work with Invoices, not direct Charges.  From [Stripe's documentation about Customer credit balances](https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/customer/balance) (emphasis added):

> Keep the following in mind when you work with credit balances:
>
> - **The credit balance automatically applies to the next finalized invoice to a customer.**
> - **You ​​can’t choose a specific invoice to apply the credit balance to.**
> - **You ​​can’t apply the credit balance to an invoice.**
> - The credit balance is in the customer’s currency.

If you create and finalize a non-zero Invoice for the Customer the credit balance should apply to that Invoice.